# joomla! Integrate Php Code

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I am new to Joomla. I have created a login form with ChronoForms and linked up with a menu which is fine. Now I need to get data from these forms and matched data with login table. I have already written script for authentication etc. In this script I am connecting to another mysql server which is different from localhost mysql server. After login I need to show a table which is based on connected user. I have also written php scripting to create this table.

The only problem is that I dont' know how to setup all these things together. Please advice

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is much too broad a question.  You should split the problem into more specific parts and ask those

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you have described correctly it all comes down to write the sql queries to check the data stored by ChronoForms against the (default prefixed) `jos_users` data.

Answer (score 0):

I am in a similar position and found an answer here: [Custom php code in Joomla page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4476206/custom-php-code-in-joomla-page)

The suggestion is to use the Jumi extension which allows you to write PHP, Javascript, HTML in place. Solves my problem nicely.