# Custom php code in Joomla page

Tags: php, joomla

I'm trying to change the source of a table in a Joomla 1.5.9 page from hardcoded html in the page to getting the information from a SQL database. What is the proper way to do this? Create a new model or component and somehow use that in the page?

I found these:
http://docs.joomla.org/Tutorial:How_to_use_the_database_classes_in_your_script
http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_use_the_database_classes_in_your_script

But I'm not sure where to write the php code and how to access it in the page. If somebody could point me to a basic tutorial for custom php or whatever it's called, I'm new to webb development, I'd be happy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [Jumi extension](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/edition/custom-code-in-content/1023) to add custom PHP code to a Joomla page or module.

Answer (score 1):

You Can install The Php Pages Component in joomla 1.5 .Where you can write your  custom  php code  in joomla .

Also using this Php Pages Component you can Also write the query in the Php Code Itself.

So That you can extract the data from the database.