# Adding own code into Joomla 3.0

Tags: php, javascript, joomla

I am pretty new to Joomla and i want to add my own HTML, PHP and Javascript code into  my joomla website.

I have been looking at this question:

[Custom php code in Joomla page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4476206/custom-php-code-in-joomla-page)

How ever it seems that the Jumi plugin or extension is only for 1.4 - 1.6 and i'm running joomla 3.0

I was wondering if any of you guys know or use any form of extension to add your own code into your joomla website!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure where you found **1.4 and 1.6** from, but Jumi is definitely compatible with Joomla 3.x, as you see see in the following link:

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/edition/custom-code-in-content/1023

it has the image:

[image]

Download and install the extension and don't forget to read the documentation through if you have issues, as most people seem to forget this ;)

Answer (score 0):

if you waht to add code in sens of your articles will contain code ( PHP, javascript & HTML)
then create simple module try to find some module generator on the net then affect that module to a position and load that module in your article like this {loadmodule position}

Comment: But what if i want to add a PHP class, or a css file or any other relevent thing that you need to build decent website functionality

Comment: it's the same since a module in like a bootstrap script you can instanciate your class without any problem